# How to create (or remove) items from a list if they are superstrings in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Using Python here. I have two lists, like so:

```
a = ["table_a", "table_b", "table_c", "xyz", "abc"]
b = ["x", "c"]
```

What I'd like is to derive a list that outputs:

```
c = ["table_a", "table_b"]
```

If the elements of `b` are found in the elements of `a`, I don't want them.

Almost all list comprehension methods are forward-only - meaning if the element from a is in b, then remove (or keep) it. But I'd like the opposite. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try list-comprehension + `all()`:

```py
a = ["table_a", "table_b", "table_c", "xyz", "abc"]
b = ["x", "c"]

c = [v for v in a if all(l not in v for l in b)]
print(c)
```

Prints:

```
['table_a', 'table_b']
```